# Creating a terrain from a heightmap

Tags: java, lwjgl, floor, heightmap

I want to create realistic terrain using java and lwjgl.
At now i have double[100][100] with my heightmap and function redering every triangle from a list.

In example - drawing smal "floor" chunk with two triangles:

```
triangles.add(new Triangle(new Vector3f(x, (float) map[x][z] * 100, z),
                    new Vector3f(+0.5f, 1, -0.5f),
                    new Vector3f(-0.5f, 1, -0.5f),
                    new Vector3f(+0.5f, 1, +0.5f), rgb, rgb, rgb));

triangles.add(new Triangle(new Vector3f(x, (float) map[x][z] * 100, z),
                    new Vector3f(-0.5f, 1, +0.5f),
                    new Vector3f(-0.5f, 1, -0.5f),
                    new Vector3f(+0.5f, 1, +0.5f), rgb, rgb, rgb));
```

triangles parameters is:

start point XYZ coordinates,
first triangle point "sub" coords,
second triangle point "sub" coords,
third triangle point "sub" coords,
rgb for first point,
rgb color for second point,
rgb color for third point,

I can`t do it... I think it is very easy and I`m so stupid or so tired. Can you help me?

Comment: Why are there 4 `Vector3f`'s in Triangle?

Comment: Function works that: render triangle using the 2,3 and 4 vector and move triangle to it coords using glTranslatef.